# PC POST issue four beeps and no video signal

Tags: motherboard, bios, desktop-computer, post

in last week i had a problem with my pc. In POST step i haven't received no beeps and no signal video. I tried to start it without HD , video card, resetting bios, no of this steps had solves my problem After that i bought a new PSU but also with that no luck. Yesterday i had installed a new motherboard and in POST step i recieving 4 shorts beeps and also in this case no video signal. According with motherboard manual 4 beeps stands for "System Timer Failure" but what is exactly the problem and how can fix it. Thanks in advance

Comment: [SOLVED: When computer starts 4 beeps then nothing - Desktop PC - iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/270179/When+computer+starts+4+beeps+then+nothing)

Comment: [4 Beeps system timer failure - \[Solved\] - Motherboards](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/314251-30-beeps-system-timer-failure)

Comment: Both of the above links indicate that there was a defective RAM stick.